# Typed.js Text Not Appearing

Tags: javascript, typed.js

I'm trying to implement the new ES6 module version of [Typed.js](http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/) (not the jQuery version), but the text isn't appearing - only the cursor (which remains stationary and doesn't blink.)

I installed the library without a problem through NPM and am compiling with Webpack. When I check my compiled `app.js` the library appears. `app.js` is loading on the page correctly and I see no errors in the console. Just a stationary cursor where my dynamically-typed text should be appearing.

Here's my code (mostly just the example from the official site):

**typewriter.js**

```
import Typed from 'typed.js';

var typed = new Typed('#typed-text', {
  strings: ["First sentence.", "Second sentence."],
  typeSpeed: 30
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="column">
  <p id="typed-text"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a hunch, how are you loading the script?.  If it's in the head, then the DOM has not yet been rendered.  You could wait for onload event, or place your script after your HTML before the closing body tag.

Comment: Just before the closing body tag, thanks.

Comment: yes,.. It's a common way to load scripts anyway as it can make your first page render faster.

Comment: Try to eliminate possible reasons, for instance to eliminate if the page is somehow not loaded enough you could try wrapping in a setTimout(function(){},10) or smt to be sure, in my case i got it working by wrapping it in a document.body.contains() to check if the requested element exists before executing the code. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Typed.js renders your text in a `<span>`. Since your javascript is outputting `strings` into `typed-text`, and since you want to format your strings in paragraph form, you want to define your `<span>` like so:

**index.html**

```
<div class="column">
<p>
<span id="typed-text"></span>
</p>
</div>
```